# Powershell in batch file - keep wildcard matching when replacing?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch

I'm using this as part of a Powershell command in a batch file to replace text in another file:

`-replace 'contrast=.*? -b:v', 'contrast=.*?,fps=%FRAMERATE% -b:v'`

The file being altered might have a specific contrast value there like this:

`contrast=1.03`

If I try to use a wildcard `.*?` like shown above, it doesn't retain the 1.03 value for contrast, it simply replaces it with the literal wildcard characters so I end up with `contrast=.*?` in the altered file.

The contrast value could change. Is there any way to tell Powershell, whatever that value is in the first part of the replace command, it needs to stay the same in the next part?

Someone said put it in square brackets (and those would need escaping since it's in a batch file) but that doesn't work, this:

`-replace 'contrast=/[.*?/] -b:v', 'contrast=/[.*?/],fps=%FRAMERATE% -b:v'`

All that does is gives me this in the altered file: `contrast=/[.*?/]`

I am sure there's some weird combination or way to do this I just can't find out how.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can shed some light on it.

Comment: it looks like you are using windows filesystem wildcards ... and those are NOT the same thing as _regex_ wildcards. [*grin*] please read up on `.`, `*`, and `+` in regex patterns.

Comment: I'm using a wildcard sequence `.*?` that works in dozens of other cases, except this. I tried with just an asterisk and that doesn't work.

Comment: I have worked around this by swapping my ffmpeg command around (so there's some end characters I can always refer to, instead of a string that might change) but as far as the question goes, it's not answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can! `-replace` supports using capture groups, and automatically sets them as a variable `$1`,`$2`, etc you can use:

```
# Example input text
$text = 'contrast=1.03 -b:v
contrast=2.34 -b:v
contrast=6.66 -b:v'

$text -replace '(.*?) -b:v', '$1,fps=%FRAMERATE% -b:v'

# Output:
contrast=1.03,fps=%FRAMERATE% -b:v
contrast=2.34,fps=%FRAMERATE% -b:v
contrast=6.66,fps=%FRAMERATE% -b:v
```

`$1` is not a powershell variable, so the `$` must be literal in your replace string. If you do want to use variables in your regex, make sure you escape it:

```
$text -replace '(.*?) -b:v', "`$1,fps=$framerate -b:v"
```

Check out the "Replace using capture groups" section on [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html) for more examples.